# Why is the time complexity of a recursive function 2^n?

Tags: recursion

The time complexity of a recursive function with two branches is supposed to be O(2^n).

Mergesort, which can be solved recursively, has a time complexity of O(n logn).

What am I missing here?

Comment: Add more context to the question.

Comment: What do you mean by *recursive function with two branches*?

Comment: You can also have recursive functions with time complexitiy O(1) (although they may be pretty useless)  `function x(n) { return n == 1 ? 1 : x(1);}` It's recursive,but O(1) as there are at most two calls to `x` regardless how big `n` gets.

Comment: Your premise in the first sentence is incorrect--there is no relation between the time complexity and number of recursive calls. Can you cite where this notion came from? For starters, you have to define `n`. An inorder tree walk is considered to be `O(n)` where `n` is the number of nodes in the tree, not `O(n^2`). It has two recursive calls. Please define the problem space and terminology a bit more clearly so answers can be precise and I get a sense of your understanding fully. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The **branching number** is not sufficient to compute the complexity. Another number you need is the **depth**.

In mergesort, the length of the subarray is divided by 2 at each recursive call. As a result, the depth of the recursion tree is `log2 n`. The total number of recursive calls is `2^(log2 n) == n`. Note that `n` is not the complexity of the algorithm: it's only the number of recursive calls. To get the complexity of the algorithm you need to sum up the number of operations performed in each recursive call.

If you implement fibonacci naively by writing:

```py
def fib(n):
  if n == 0 or n == 1:
    return 1
  else:
    return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)
```

Then the variable `n` only reduces by 1 or 2 at each recursive call, so the depth of the branches in the recursive tree will be between n and n/2. The total number of recursive calls is somewhere between `2^n` and `2^(n/2)`.